# Reverse only numbers from file

Tags: python, file, reverse, enumerate

How can I reverse only number and not the text from this ?

```
datas.txt
```

```
Bungo Charlie
Bungo Echo
Bungo Bravo
Bungo Tango
Bungo Alpha
```

```
with open('datas.txt', 'r') as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        print('{}. {}'.format(i+1, line.strip()))
```

**Expectation:**

```
5. Bungo Charlie
4. Bungo Echo
3. Bungo Bravo
2. Bungo Tango
1. Bungo Alpha
```

**What I got :**

```
1. Bungo Charlie
2. Bungo Echo
3. Bungo Bravo
4. Bungo Tango
5. Bungo Alpha
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply using the `reversed()` function will reverse everything:

```
for i, line in reversed(list(enumerate(f))
```

If you'd like to only reverse the numbers, you can do it selectively (but messily) like so:

```
reversed(list(enumerate(reversed(f))))
```

If you want something cleaner, you can define a function using `zip()`:

```
def reverse_enumerate(x):
    return zip(reversed(range(len(x))), reversed(x))
```

Comment: I didn’t downvote but i’d guess it’s because you showed no attempt